# WordPress Dutch characters encoding problem

Tags: mysql, encoding, characters

I am using the Dutch special characters like ï and it is being converted to u00ef.

I have tried ut8_unicode_ci in wp-config and in the database tables where the value is saved but it is still saved in the database as encoded characters. I want to display it as Dutch characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Turns out the problem was with I was using json_enode to convert the data in to json before inserting it in to database and it was causing the encoding of the characters I have used `json_encode($url,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` and now its working properly.